# posting to Facebook page as admin using the Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm posing updates to our website on a Facebook page. This stopped working a while ago. I updated everything to the latest API and was able to post, but only as a post from the logged in user to the page, not as the page admin. I discovered that forcing the 'default_graph_version' to 'v2.2' made things work as expected. My question:

what do I need to change to make posting on a page as the page (so NOT as the user with the admin rights) possible using the latest default_graph_version?

I had to change:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook( [
    "app_id"     => "%appId%",   //* this is the appId for amazingjokes
    "app_secret" => "%appSecret%",
] );
```

to this:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook( [
    "app_id"     => "%appId%",   //* this is the appId for amazingjokes
    "app_secret" => "%appSecret%",
    "default_graph_version" => 'v2.2'
] );
```

to make things work. I'm posting the content like this:

```
    $attachment = [
        "message"     => "test amazingjokes.com",
        "name"        => "amazingjokes test",
        "caption"     => "your daily laugh!",
        "link"        => "http://www.amazingjokes.com/",
        "description" => "description test"
        "picture"     => "http://www.amazingjokes.com/img/2016/581750c9c7979_Merry....jpg"
    ];

    try{
        $result = $fb->post( "419661214806422/feed", $attachment, $accessToken );
    } catch( Exception $e ){
        die( "<pre>" . print_r( $e, true ) . "</pre>" );
    }
```

It works using v2.2 of the Graph Version, so I'm sure I have my permissions correct ('manage_pages' and 'publish_pages')

Comment: Use a page access token.

Comment: `publish_pages` has only been introduced with v2.3 - so I am pretty sure you do _not_ have the correct permissions. Go debug your user access token that was used to request the page token, and check what permissions it actually contains.

Comment: @CBroe... it works though... but I'll do that